# The R-code in SQL Server won't find package psych

Tags: sql-server, r

I tried to run R code in SQL Server but it won't run although it runs or R. How can I get R running properly on SQL Server such that it finds the package psych? I tested examples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-working-with-inputs-and-outputs to make sure that at least some R code works properly in SQL Server.

I tried

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script    
    @language = N'R'    
   , @script = N'a1=c(4,3,4,5,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,3,5,1,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,1,5,5,3,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,1,5,5,5,4,4,3,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,2,4,4,5,3,4,4,4,5,4,5,3,5,5,5,4,5,5,2,1,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,5)
a1=c(4,3,4,5,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,3,5,1,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,1,5,5,3,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,1,5,5,5,4,4,3,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,2,4,4,5,3,4,4,4,5,4,5,3,5,5,5,4,5,5,2,1,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,5)
a2=c(4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,4,1,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,1,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,2,4,5,4,5,5,4,2,5,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,3,4,5,5,5,4,4,5,2,2,2,4,5,4,3,5,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,5,5,4,1,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4)
a3=c(5,4,5,3,2,4,4,4,4,3,4,5,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,5,2,4,2,2,4,2,4,5,4,3,4,2,4,4,1,1,4,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,4,2,5,4,3,3,4,3,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,4,2,2,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,4,4,2,4,2,3,2,5,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,4,1,2,3,2,4,5,3,3,2,3,4,5,3,4,3,4,1,3,4,4,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,2,4,4,4,3,3,2,4,4,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,4,2,3,3,4,4,3,5,2,3,2)
a4=c(2,4,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,4,1,1,2,4,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,4,5,2,1,1,2,1,2,4,3,4,2,4,1,4,3,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,4,1,1,2,2,3,5,2,2,2,1,2,4,2,5,1,2,1,3,2,4,2,2,2,4,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,4,2,2,4,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,4,1,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,3,2,4,3,2,2,2,2,4,1,2,2,2,2,1,5,2,4,5,2,2,2,3,1)
a5=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,1,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,1,5,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,1,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,2,4,1,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,1,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4.56579,5,4,4)
a6=c(2,2,3,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,2,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,5,3,4,4,4,5,4,4,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,3,2,1,4,4,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,1,4,4,4,5,4,5,2,3,1,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,4,3,4,2,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,2,2,4,4,2,1,4,3,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,3,5,4,4,5,3,2,3,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,2,4,2,5)
a7=c(2,2,4,1,2,1,2,2,2,4,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,4,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,5,4,1,1,4,1,3,2,5,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,4,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,4,1,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,2,2,1,5,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,3,2,4,2,3,2)
a8=c(4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,3,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,5,3,4,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,1,4,5,5,3,2,4,3,4,5,5,1,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,5,5,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,4,3,5,4,5,4,2,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,3,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,3,4,2,4,4,1,5,4,4)
a9=c(2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,4,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,4,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1)
a10=c(5,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,3,5,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,1,4,4,4,5,3,4,4,3,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,3,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,3,4,3,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,5,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,3,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4)
a11=c(4,4,5,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,5,4,4,5,4,3,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,3,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,2,5,4,4,5,3,5,3,5,5,4,5,3,4,5,4,4,4,4,2,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,4,4,5,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,4,3,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,5,4,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,3,4,4)
a12=c(2,4,4,2,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,3,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,3,1,5,3,2,2,4,3,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,3,4,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,4,3,2,2,2,3,3)
a13=c(4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,3,2,4,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,4,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,4,4,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,4,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,4,1,1,1,2,2,4,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,1.99342,2,3,2)
a14=c(4,3,5,5,5,4,4,5,4,4,2,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,2,5,5,4,3,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,3,5,4,2,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,3,5,3,4,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,2,5,3,3,4,2,2,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,2,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,5,5,4,4,5)
a15=c(2,2,2,2,2,1,4,2,3,4,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,4,3,4,3,4,1,1,5,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,4,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,4,2,1,1,1,1,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,4,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,2,4,1,2,2,2,2,4,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1)
a16=c(2,3,4,4,4,4,5,4,3,3,2,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,5,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,1,4,4,4,2,3,4,3,4,4,3,1,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,2,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,3,3,5,4,4,4,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,3,2,4,4,5,3,4,3,4,5,3.82237,4,4,4)
a17=c(4,4,3,5,4,5,4,4,3,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,3,5,3,4,4,4,4,3,4,5,4,4,4,3,5,5,4,3,4,1,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,1,4,4,5,5,4,3,4,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,2,4,4,4,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,4,3,4,2,5,3,5,5,4,4,4,2,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,2,3,4,4,2,3,3,4,4,3,5,3,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,3,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,3,4,4,5,4,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,4)
a18=c(4,3,4,4,5,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,5,3,2,3,3,4,4,3,2,4,3,3,4,2,4,4,3,4,1,3,3,4,5,2,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,5,2,4,4,4,3,3,5,3,2,4,4,4,4,5,3,3,4,2,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,3,3,3,4,3,3,4,4,2,3,3,5,3,3,4,2,2,3,2,4,3,4,5,2,4,4,2,4,2,5,4,2,2,4,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,1,5,4,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,2,5,4,3,3)
a19=c(4,4,4,5,5,4,5,3,4,3,4,3,4,5,2,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,2,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,1,5,4,3,5,3,4,4,4,4,4,1,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,3,5,5,5,3,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,5,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,2,5,5,4,5,4,2,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,3,5,4,3,4,4,4,5,5,3,4,3,5,2,5,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,3,4,3,2,4,4,5,4)
a20=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,1,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,1,5,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,1,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,2,4,1,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,1,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4.56579,5,4,4)
options(warn=-1);a=cbind(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20)
library(psych);
result = tryCatch(alpha(a), warning = function(w) {tryCatch(alpha(a,check.keys=TRUE),warning = function(w) { print("Error, lets try some likelihood!" ) })})
cor(a, method = c("spearman"))'    
   , @input_data_1 = N' SELECT 1 as Temp1'    
   WITH RESULT SETS (([Col1] char(20) NOT NULL));
```

The error was

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 1
>   A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   An external script error occurred:
>      Error in library(psych) : there is no package called 'psych'
>      Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library

Comment: Have you made sure that library is [installed correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/packages-installed-in-user-libraries) on the server?

Comment: I think they are as the library works in R. But I'm not sure if the sql server management studio calls correctly R.

Comment: Are they in the default library? The article specifically mentions they need to be, unlike in R where it is more flexible about using user libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess they are not as I need to load the library before I can do the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use libraries in R via SQL Server, you need to [ensure that the packages are in the default library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/packages-installed-in-user-libraries). R itself is more flexible about this, but SQL Server requires stricter loading:

> Therefore, when you migrate R solutions to run in SQL Server, it is
> important that you do the following:
>
> - Install any packages that you
>   need to the default library. Edit code to ensure that packages are
>   loaded from the default library, not from ad hoc directories or user
>   libraries.
> - Check your code to make sure that there are no calls to
>   uninstalled packages.
> - Modify any code that would try to install
>   packages dynamically.